# how to create Heroku procfile for windows?

Tags: heroku, translation, procfile

Im a newbie trying to make a django app, but unfortunately my os is windows.
Heroku docs is written for linux so I cant get sufficient information for app development on windows 7.
First how can I make procfile using window cmd?
Is there any command language translation docs?(linux->windows)

Comment: I'm not sure Foreman works on Windows - also the Procfile is meant to be something that you would include in your deployments to Heroku - a windows specific one would break.

Answer (score 16):

Regarding creation of text file in cmd shell:

`echo web: run this thing >Procfile`

this will create `Procfile` with `web: run this thing` inside (obviously).

Also You can use any text editor, `notepad` will fit perfectly.

And one thing, that wasn't obvious for me, therefore can also be helpfull to someone else.
`Procfile should be a text file` is a bit misleading, do NOT save `Procfile` as `Procfile.txt` or it will not be recognised. Just leave it plain and simple `Procfile` without any file format.

Answer (score 8):

When you're using Windows for development, and your procfile contains for example $JAVA_OPTS (or anything else system dependent), then

- besides of `Procfile` with Linux syntax (with for example: $JAVA_OPTS), for Heroku, you need
- `Procfile.windows` with Windows syntax (where you can write for example" %JAVA_OPTS%), and you point to it while working with Heroku localy: `heroku local web -f procfile.windows`

Answer (score 3):

A [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) should be a text file, called `Procfile`, sitting in the root directory of your app.

It's the same for Windows or Linux or OS X.

It should specify the command Heroku should use to start your app - so it's not really about linux or windows.

So to answer your question: use a text editor.  Any text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the file with name `procfile`. If your editor is intelligent enough as mine to understand the files like `procfile` have a `Heroku` icon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`gunicorn` doesn't work on Windows so you'll want a Procfile.windows that will locally host your app in a way that doesn't require gunicorn (such as the way you would normally do it).

`web: ~what you would normally use to start your app~`

Answer (score 0):

web: gunicorn app_name.wsgi
write your own application name instead of app_name and file name just save without any Extention (Procfile).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what the answer is about? Is it a command prompt? Maybe add a bit more context?

Comment: Write your procfile name like ( Procfile ) no need to add any type of extension and inside the Procfile write web: gunicorn app_name.wsgi.                                  you have to write your application name instead of app_name and also install gunicorn in your project.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! You can simply add that to the answer and delete the comment. Makes it easier for others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A file named `Procfile` is required in the root of your Heroku project. The following is a basic example of the content to be created for a Django project:

```
web: gunicorn your_app_name.wsgi --log-file
```

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) the full docs from Heroku.